# How to use a ipynb source file as a notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I download a jupiter notebook file as a text (it was the only possible option, beacause it was the content of a web page), so now I have a .txt file with the source code like:

```
"metadata": {
 "language_info": {
  "codemirror_mode": {
   "name": "ipython",
   "version": 3
  },
  "file_extension": ".py",
  "mimetype": "text/x-python",
...
```

How can I use it as a .ipynb file?

Comment: you can load it in jupyter notebook easily, start your jupyter notebook as some location put that `.ipynb` file there, you will see the file inside jupyter notebook explorer. You can download it as .py from jupyter also.

Comment: The problem is that I have a .txt file and not a .ipynb file

Comment: just replace the extension with `.ipynb` and try